# Strict parsing into POJOs with KMongo

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, kmongo

When I `find` documents in my collections and parse them into POJOs, I would like to see exceptions, if additional keys are available in the MongoDB, that do not correspondent to my POJO.
Can't find a way to configure that.

What I do

```
data class MyPojo(var a: Int)

val mongoClient = KMongo.createClient(...)
val collection = mongoClient...
val results = collection.aggregate<MyPojo>(...)
```

and if a result document is

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```

What I get:

```
MyPojo(a=1)
```

I would like to see an exception of sort

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonDecodingException: Invalid JSON...: Encountered an unknown key b
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `strictMode = true` in your JsonConfiguration for example:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    serialization(
        contentType = ContentType.Application.Json,
        json = Json(
            JsonConfiguration(
                strictMode = true,
                prettyPrint = true
            )
        )
    )
}
```